# How to implemented display text as stream , eg the example app 'Text Transmuter'

Tags: ios

I see the app 'play' a animation that is very interesting... what's the solution for this type purpose ? thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: A little more information please? Which app? Which animation? And what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/mt/app/text-transmuter/id421783038?mt=it

it show the text as animation character